Potential flow over a sphere in circular motion
The potential for a sphere moving in a straight line with a constant velocity U in an incompressible, inviscid and irrotational fluid is given by the following potential:
$$
\phi =−U \left(r+\frac{a^3}{r^2} \right) \cos\theta$$
$$
I would like to know the equation for a sphere which is moving in a circular orbit with a  uniform angular velocity. How do I manage it? Should I impose a reference frame solidal with the sphere and then make the reference frame to turn as it would be seen from an absolute reference frame? Or should I impose an absolute reference frame? What is the equation of the potential for this kind of motion?

Is the diameter of the sphere very small compared to the diameter of the circular orbit?

Might be. But I do not want to think to it as the general case of a sphere in the freestream

is $r$ a coordinate, or the radius of the sphere? Or is $a$ the radius? Just saying: "The potential for a sphere ($R$) moving in a straight line with a constant velocity $U$ is..." would clear it all up. So would a figure.

We examine a sphere of radius $a$ moving in a circular path of radius $R$ with a constant angular velocity $\Omega$, where the fluid surrounding the sphere is assumed to be incompressible, inviscid, and irrotational. We seek the velocity potential $\phi$ describing the flow field. The choice of a rotating frame, specifically a non-inertial frame attached to the sphere and rotating with the same angular velocity $\Omega$, makes the sphere stationary in this frame, thereby simplifying the analysis and allowing for a time-independent potential.
In this rotating frame, the total potential $\phi$ can be expressed as the sum of several components. The translational potential $\phi_{\text{trans}}$ arises from the relative motion of the fluid in the rotating frame as it would be seen by a stationary observer in that rotating frame. It is similar to the potential for linear motion but is scaled by $U = \Omega R$, which represents the tangential velocity of the sphere in the inertial frame. The translational potential is given by $\phi_{\text{trans}} = -\Omega R \left( r + \frac{a^3}{r^2} \right) \cos\theta$. The centrifugal potential $\phi_{\text{cent}}$ arises from the non-inertial nature of the rotating frame and represents the outward force experienced by fluid elements due to the rotation, given by $\phi_{\text{cent}} = \frac{1}{2} \Omega^2 r^2 \sin^2\theta$. The total potential is obtained by superimposing these components: $\phi = \phi_{\text{trans}} + \phi_{\text{cent}} = -\Omega R \left( r + \frac{a^3}{r^2} \right) \cos\theta + \frac{1}{2} \Omega^2 r^2 \sin^2\theta$.
The Coriolis force, given by $-2\rho \mathbf{\Omega} \times \mathbf{v'}$ where $\mathbf{v'}$ is the velocity in the rotating frame, exists in this frame but for steady-state analysis, its effects are indirectly accounted for by the centrifugal term. For transient flows, both the Coriolis force and time-dependent terms would need consideration. The potential derived in the rotating frame is steady, thus excluding time-dependent terms like $\cos(\Omega t)$.
The potential must satisfy Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ in the fluid domain, match the far-field flow at infinity, and ensure zero normal velocity at the sphere's surface. The velocity field in the rotating frame, obtained as $\mathbf{v} = \nabla \phi$, gives in spherical coordinates: $v_r = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = -\Omega R \left( 1 - \frac{2a^3}{r^3} \right) \cos\theta + \Omega^2 r \sin^2\theta$, $v_\theta = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} = \Omega R \left( 1 + \frac{a^3}{2r^3} \right) \sin\theta + \Omega^2 r \sin\theta \cos\theta$, and $v_\phi = 0$.
The pressure field follows from Bernoulli's equation for steady, inviscid, and irrotational flow: $p + \frac{1}{2} \rho |\mathbf{v}|^2 + \rho \phi = \text{constant}$, where $p$ is pressure, $\rho$ is fluid density, and $|\mathbf{v}|$ is fluid velocity magnitude.
The complete solution for the potential $\phi$ is thus:
$$\phi = -\Omega R \left( r + \frac{a^3}{r^2} \right) \cos\theta + \frac{1}{2} \Omega^2 r^2 \sin^2\theta $$
This solution assumes an inviscid and irrotational fluid, neglecting real-world viscous effects and transient behaviors during rotation initiation. The rotating frame approach provides a steady-state description where the sphere appears stationary while properly accounting for both translational and centrifugal effects in the flow field.
